# How to make md-card in column?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Even when I copy official demo it displays in row. layout="column" doesn't help. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have the `layout` attribute specified on the parent of the card if you want the card to behave as a columnar card (i.e. two card with parent `layout=column` will be vertically aligned so one is above and the other below)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPjmJd shows `layout=columns` and you can see all the 3 cards on top of one another.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOqmMJ shows `layout=row` and you can see all the 3 cards next to one another.